# Tomcat 8.0.33 doesn't support reverseProxy with nginx?

Tags: nginx, tomcat, jira

I can’t find information specifically about Tomcat version 8.0.33, but as I understand it, it only supports AJP for Proxy?

I trying install nginx with old jira 7.2.3 with SSL. And JIRA (Tomcat) still use his cacert and keystore. Why?

```
               <Connector port="8080"
                maxThreads="150"
                minSpareThreads="25"
                connectionTimeout="20000"
                enableLookups="false"
                maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                useBodyEncodingForURI="true"
                redirectPort="8443"
                acceptCount="100"
                disableUploadTimeout="true"
                proxyName="my.foo.bar"
                proxyPort="443"
                scheme="https"
                secure="true"/>
```

and nginx.

```
server {
        listen  80 default_server;
        server_name my.foo.bar;
        return  301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}


server {
        listen 443 ssl;
        server_name my.foo.bar;
        ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/cert.pem;
        ssl_session_timeout     5m;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384';

        proxy_http_version      1.1;
        gzip on;
        gzip_http_version       1.1;
        gzip_comp_level         6;
        gzip_proxied            any;
        gzip_types              text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript image/png image/svg+xml;

     location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        client_max_body_size 100M;
 }
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error_my.foo.bar.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access_my.foo.bar.log;
}
```

What could I set up wrong? No redirect, no https. only http works (redirect works if I setup listen port to 8080)

Comment: If you're not even getting SSL to work then it's not Tomcat.  The [documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/proxy-howto.html), while prehistoric (Tomcat 8.0.x hasn't been supported in about 5 years), uses the HTTP Proxy of Apache, not AJP.  I'd get Nginx working with SSL first.

Comment: @stdunbar echo | openssl s_client -showcerts -servername my.foo.bar -connect my.foo.bar:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -inform pem -noout -text send me cerficate